# ggplot percentages multiplied by 100

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot to make a plot showing  percentages on the yaxis. 
here's the data and code i used

```
data<-"yrs.1.17 yrs.18.44 yrs.45.64 yrs.65.84 yrs.85.
1     4.53     35.12     32.93     22.86    4.57
2     4.01     34.74     34.19     22.71    4.34
3     4.75     33.23     35.19     22.28    4.51
4     4.60     34.04     36.93     20.70    3.56
5     4.80     33.82     37.69     19.97    3.52
6     4.30     35.09     37.08     19.83    3.65
7     3.65     38.08     36.19     19.18    2.85
8     3.72     38.11     36.10     19.22    2.86"

mydata<- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE)


year<-c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013)
df<-data.frame(year,mydata)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
newdf<-melt(df,'year')
ggplot(newdf,aes(x=year,y=value,group=variable,color=variable))+ geom_line(size=1)+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=year)+xlab("Year")+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent,limits=c(1,50),breaks=seq(5,50,by=5))+ylab("Age groups")+
geom_point(aes(shape=variable),size=3)+
ggtitle("Age groups of people between 2006 and 2013")+
theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.justification=c(0.6,0.6), legend.position=c(0.95,0.95), legend.text = element_text(size=9), 
axis.text = element_text(size=9), axis.title = element_text(size=9), plot.title=element_text(size = 9))
```

As you can see in the output the percentages are all multiplied by 100.  Is there a way to get the  correct percentages.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have  tried using the following in the code, but there is no change.

scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())

Comment: Nice example for your first question (plus1). If Gregor has answered your question you can mark so it by clicking on the tick next to it (you can also tap the <arrow up> there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide by 100:

```
ggplot(newdf,
  aes(
    x = year,
    y = value / 100, # here divide by 100
    group = variable,
    color = variable
  )
) + 
  geom_line(size=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=year) + 
  xlab("Year") + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = percent,
    limits = c(.01, .5),            # here divide by 100
    breaks = seq(.05, .5, by = .05) # here divide by 100
  ) +
  ylab("Age groups") +
  geom_point(aes(shape = variable), size=3) +
  ggtitle("Age groups of people between 2006 and 2013") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.justification = c(0.6, 0.6),
        legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 9),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 9))
```

As a side-note, rather than all the manual setting of `element_text(size = 9)`, most themes take a `base_size` argument, so using `theme_grey(9)` or `theme_classic(9)` will do most of the work for you. You may still need to tweak the title.

Comment: If Gregor's suggestion does not work, a quick fix is ``labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")``  May be needed when using ``y = cumsum(...count...)``, because dividing by 100 does not seem to work in this case.